# Jquery links to animate scrolling div rather then the entire page

Tags: jquery

I'm using a older script that uses jquery anchor links to animate the page to the anchor. It works great, but I need it to just animate the content of a particular div, rather then the entire page. Any idea on how to target a div rather then the page?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.anchorLink").anchorAnimate()
});

jQuery.fn.anchorAnimate = function(settings) {

    settings = jQuery.extend({
        speed : 1100
    }, settings);   

    return this.each(function(){
        var caller = this
        $(caller).click(function (event) {  
            event.preventDefault()
            var locationHref = window.location.href
            var elementClick = $(caller).attr("href")

            var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
            $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, function() {
                window.location.hash = elementClick
            });
            return false;
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Just as a general comment, it is generally a bad idea to rely on Javascript's automatic semi-colon insertion, this is a "feature" of the language that is generally considered a Bad Thing and will trip you up if you are not careful. Making line endings explicit will help you prevent bugs. If you really don't like line endings, maybe try using CoffeeScript instead, the alternate syntax does not require line endings, but the JS it generates will be valid and have line endings in the correct places.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you have to change (if I understand your question right) is the following code:

```
$("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, function() {
            window.location.hash = elementClick
        });
```

and change it to

```
$("#yourDivToAnimateId").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, function() {
            window.location.hash = elementClick
        });
```

and the div you want to animate must have its id set to "yourDivToAnimateId". For more information on jQuery selectors click [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

The reason the current code animates the whole page is that it targets the html and body tags if they are not currently being animated.

You can also use

```
$("#yourDivToAnimateId:not(:animated)").animate(...)
```

to prevent a new animation of the selected div to be started while a previous animation is running.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I wasn't able to get it working using the solution above. Is there a way just to use jquery to animate the contents of a div (overflow:scroll;) to a certain ID# within that div?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to animate each element nested in a specified div, starting from the first child of the div and finishing at the element with a specified id? If so and the id you seek within that div is its direct child, you can make use of [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and [:lt()](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) functions. You may edit your question to include the actual HTML the js will be working on to further clarify your needs